# Как посмотреть на GitHub все созданные ветки

Tags: git, github

Я создал локальный репозиторий и залил его на GitHub:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "f"
$ git branch dev
$ git checkout dev
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "s"
$ git checkout master
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Zhukovdpua/1.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

Как теперь там посмотреть содержимое ветки dev? Я вижу только master
https://github.com/Zhukovdpua/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ветка dev не загружена. Нужно переключиться в неё и запушить.

Или можно запушить все имеющиеся ветки с параметром `--all`:

```
git push --all origin
```

PS.  *Ещё у вас в ветке dev нет никаких изменений по сравнению с master (по крайней мере в приведённых командах этого не видно), поэтому может быть, что она все равно не загрузится, так как грузить нечего.*

Comment: Для push'а даже неактичной ветки переключаться не обязательно.